# How to check if Sidebar is visible/hidden?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

How to check if sidebar is visible in Sublime Text 3?

This doesn't work:

```py
state1_w = v.viewport_extent()[0]
v.window().run_command("toggle_side_bar")
state2_w = v.viewport_extent()[0]
v.window().run_command("toggle_side_bar")
print('state1_w', state1_w)
print('state2_w', state2_w)
if state1_w and state2_w:
  return (state1_w < state2_w)
```

It's toggling the sidebar and checking the layout width, but unfortunately both `state1_w` and `state2_w` are same values. I think this was supposed to work in ST2 but it doesn't in ST3.

Is there another way to check whether the sidebar is visible or not in ST3?

Comment: This works fine for me...

Comment: @MattDMo if you print out `state1_w` and `state2_w` do you get different values? (check edit) It outputs the same value for me (ST3 build 3083)

Comment: I'm using build 3095, and yes, the two are different if I assign one, then toggle the side bar, then assign the other.

Answer (score 3):

Sublime Text 3 build 3098 was released just now, and it includes two new API functions:
- `Window.is_sidebar_visible()`
- `Window.set_sidebar_visible()`

Change log at https://www.sublimetext.com/3dev